# Play/pause function with multiple videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, video

HTML:

```
 <video width="840" id="video">
          <source src="{{box.video}}" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

JS:

```
video = document.querySelector("#video");
$this = $(this);
function playVideo() {
   video.play();
}
function stopVideo() {
   video.pause();
}
function pauseVideo() {
   video.pause();
}
function skip(value) {
   video.currentTime += value;
}
```

It works with one video but I've got a lot of videos on the page. So when I click another video, its getting first audio every time.

How can I use these functions with multiple videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem here is that you are using the same `id` with multiple video elements in your page, the `id` need to be unique in the page, and that's why it always stop/play the first `video` as it's the only one handled by the DOM.

The best thing is to attach the **[`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)** event listener to all videos in the page like this:

```
$("video").click(function() {
  if (this.paused)
    this.play();
  else
    this.pause();
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("video").click(function() {
  if (this.paused)
    this.play();
  else
    this.pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="240">
          <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video width="240">
          <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video width="240">
          <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: If the answer helps you, can you please upvote it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to first select all of the videos. Then I would add event listeners to each of the videos objects in the array like this:

```
const videos = document.querySelectorAll('videos')

function playVideo() {
  this.play();
}

videos.forEach( video => video.addEventListener('click',playVideo));
```